# bcdedit file output doesn't work but other commands do

Tags: c++, windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm having a very strange issue with executing a command line. The code below works without a problem:

```
ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "cmd.exe", "/C ipconfig > file_output.txt", NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

When executed, the ipconfig output is written to file_output.txt", which is exactly what I want. However when I use bcdedit:

```
ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "cmd.exe", "/C bcdedit > file_output.txt", NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

The file is generated, but nothing is in the file. I can execute that same command in cmd.exe as an Administrator and it works. I've also tried:

```
ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "cmd.exe", "/C bcdedit /enum all > file_output.txt", NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Nothing with bcdedit works. There are no errors. Here are a few other methods I've tried:

1. Using CreateProcess instead.
2. Using system instead.
3. Setting the directory to C:\Windows\System32
4. Setting the directory to C:\Windows\SysWOW64\

Again, executing the same command in cmd.exe works, but it doesn't seem to work in my code. I've been searching all day and I can't seem to find something that works. Any ideas?

---

Edit: After further debugging, now I'm seeing the following with the command.

> 'bcdedit' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
>
> 'C:\Windows\System32\bcdedit.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external c
> ommand, operable program or batch file.

I've tried all 4 methods listed above again and it apparently still cannot be recognized as a command. **bcdedit.exe does in fact exist in C:\Windows\System32**.

Comment: I'm not so sure that bash tag fits here.  Does your user have administrative privileges?  If this is compiled as an executable, try right clicking the exe, and select "run as administrator"

Comment: @Jason Yes, the user has administrator privileges. Rather the executable has a require administrator execution level.

Comment: Any chance you could post more code?

Comment: @Jason That's all the code is. Check the edit! Apparently the command is not recognized despite all 4 other methods being used. It still doesn't make a difference with runas as well.

Comment: Maybe try invoking the full path?  Don't forget \\ for \ in this case.

Comment: @Jason I tried "ShellExecute(NULL, "runas", "cmd.exe", "/C C:\\Windows\\System32\\bcdedit.exe", NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);". Still no luck. I went to the directory and bcdedit.exe does in fact exist in C:\Windows\System32\.

Comment: What is that /C option for?

Comment: @Jason /C executes the command and then closes the program immediately. The way I was able to see that unrecognized command error is by using /K. Which executes the command but keeps the console open.

Comment: have you considered using sysnative: search https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx for info.  E.g C:\Windows\Sysnative\bcdedit.exe

Answer (score 1):

That's the effect of file system redirection for 32-bit processes running on 64-bit windows.

On 64-bit windows whenever a 32-bit app attempts to access `%windir%\System32` directory, the access will be redirected to `%windir%\SysWOW64`. This process is transparent to the application and it still thinks it is accessing `%windir%\System32` directory.

So when your 32-bit app is invoking `cmd.exe` it is actually invoking the 32-bit version of `cmd.exe` which resides in `%windir%\SysWOW64`. The 32-bit version of `cmd.exe` in turn tries to invoke `bcdedit.exe` from `SysWOW64` direcory but there is no 32-bit version of `bcdedit.exe` present in `%windir%\SysWOW64` it is only present in `%windir%\System32` which the the 32-bit `cmd.exe` can not access.

To acquire more information about **File System Redirector** you can refer to the MSDN page at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx

The most convenient way to resolve that is to compile your app to 64-bit executable for running on 64-bit windows.

But if you have specific needs to keep your application 32-bit only, or if you want to have a single executable which can be run on both 32-bit and 64-bit systems then you can temporarily disable file system redirector to be able to run 64-bit version of `cmd.exe` on 64-bit windows. The information for how to do that can be found in the above posted link.

But doing so is not generally recommended, it needs through understanding of the subject and it has the potential to produce more problems than it resolves.

If there is a need for a single executable for 32-bit and 64-bit windows then the alternative is to produce both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of your app and embed the 64-bit executable in the 32-bit one as a resource. Then 32-bit app can detect whether it is running under 32-bit or 64-bit windows so either it will continues running or will extract the 64-bit executable to a temporary location to run that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I am thinking your application is running as administrator, but the `ShellExecute` command is not.  To do this, I believe you will need to make your second argument to `runas` instead of `open`. Like this:

```
ShellExecute(NULL, "runas", "cmd.exe", "/C bcdedit > file_output.txt", NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However file_output.txt is still blank.