# Rebooting to specific OS via batch file not working in C# console app

Tags: c#, batch-file, process, console-application

I have multiple operating systems installed on my PC, and the following batch file reboots to the OS specified in the argument:

**Reboot.bat**

```
@echo off

COMMENT

Argument Mapping:

{default} is for Default OS
{56273db4-58e5-11ec-924b-c48ee7d6e76a} is for Second OS
{56273dac-58e5-11ec-924b-c48ee7d6e76a} is for Third OS

ENDCOMMENT

bcdedit /bootsequence %1 /addfirst
Shutdown /r /t 0
```

And running the batch file with a shortcut specifying the target field as shown below works fine and reboots to the second OS without any user input:

```
%USERPROFILE%\Dropbox\Misc\Reboot.bat {56273db4-58e5-11ec-924b-c48ee7d6e76a}
```

But, running the bat file with that specified argument above in a C# console app shown below just reboots to the `Choose An Operating System` screen where I have to manually choose the OS. I even tried running the compiled `exe` file as administrator, but it did the same thing.

What could be wrong with the code? I'm running the latest version of Windows 10 Pro.

```
internal class Program
{
   private static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       Console.Write("Which OS do you want to reboot to?:");
       Console.WriteLine();
       Console.WriteLine();
       Console.WriteLine("[1] Default");
       Console.WriteLine("[2] Second OS");
       Console.WriteLine("[3] Third OS");
    
       var choice = Console.ReadLine();
    
       if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(choice))
       {
           switch (choice)
           {
              case "1":
                  choice = "{default}";
                  break;
    
              case "2":
                  choice = "{56273db4-58e5-11ec-924b-c48ee7d6e76a}";
                  break;
    
              case "3":
                  choice = "{56273dac-58e5-11ec-924b-c48ee7d6e76a}";
                  break;
    
              default:
                  return;
           }
       }
                
       var command = $@"{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE")}\Dropbox\Misc\Reboot.bat {choice}";
                
       ExecuteCommand(command);
   }
    
   public static void ExecuteCommand(string command)
   {
       int exitCode;
       ProcessStartInfo processInfo;
       Process process;
    
       processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + command);
       processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
       processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
       process = Process.Start(processInfo);
       process.WaitForExit();
       exitCode = process.ExitCode;
       process.Close();
   }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you remove `processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;`?

Comment: @rfmodulator This didn't work. It is still showing the `Choose An Operating System` screen on reboot. I'm thinking the `Shutdown /r /t 0` command in the batch file is causing the OS to turn off prematurely before the process has a chance to properly close, which is why the program is not behaving as it should. How can I solve that problem?

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.enableraisingevents?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It turns out that my previous code did not start the `cmd.exe` process in administrator mode, as I suspected. I made the changes below, and I executed the `cmd` commands directly instead of using a `bat` file:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Which OS do you want to reboot to?:\n");
        Console.WriteLine("[1] Default");
        Console.WriteLine("[2] Second OS");
        Console.WriteLine("[3] Third OS");

        var choice = Console.ReadLine();

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(choice))
        {
            switch (choice)
            {
                case "1":
                    choice = "default";
                    break;

                case "2":
                    choice = "56273db4-58e5-11ec-924b-c48ee7d6e76a";
                    break;

                case "3":
                    choice = "56273dac-58e5-11ec-924b-c48ee7d6e76a";
                    break;

                default:
                    return;
            }
        } 
        else
        {
            return;
        }
       
        ExecuteCommand($@"bcdedit /bootsequence {{{choice}}} /addfirst & shutdown /r /t 0");
                    
    }
    
    public static void ExecuteCommand(string command)
    {
        Process process = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Windows\System32",
            FileName = "cmd.exe",
            UseShellExecute = true,
            CreateNoWindow = false,
            Verb = "runas",
            Arguments = "/c " + command
        };
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();
        process.Close();
    }
}
```

After making these changes, I ran into another problem where the command prompt did not recognize the `bcdedit` command. This is caused by the effect of file system redirection for 32-bit processes running on 64-bit windows. So, I had to set the target platform of the console app to `X64`. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50824048/10259491) helped.